# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset error when using map function | KeyError

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, tensorflow-datasets, keyerror

I am working on my capstone project. Basically, I am trying to build a recommendation system for amazon beauty products. The dataset is a **TensorFlow dataset**.

### Some Source code that works just fine

```
 data=tfds.load('amazon_us_reviews/Beauty_v1_00', split='train')

 type: tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset
```

- Display some info about the features:

  ```
  for sample in data.take(1).as_numpy_iterator():

  pprint.pprint(sample)
  ```
- Output

  ```
    {'data': {'customer_id': b'18239070',
         'helpful_votes': 0,
         'marketplace': b'US',
         'product_category': b'Beauty',
         'product_id': b'B00LJ86MAY',
         'product_parent': b'823234087',
         'product_title': b'The Original Curly Tee Towel - T-Shirt Hair Dryi'
                      b'ng Towel Wrap (Extra Long)',
          'review_body': b'Great product, quick ship and packaged nicely with a'
                    b'ttention to detail. Thank you!',
          'review_date': b'2014-10-04',
          'review_headline': b'Very pleased!',
          'review_id': b'R24WHRN0BMM2K7',
          'star_rating': 5,
          'total_votes': 0,
          'verified_purchase': 1,
          'vine': 1}}
  ```

### Error

> I try to select only some of the columns using the map function

```
       data = data.map(lambda x: {
               "customer_id": x["customer_id"],
               "product_id": x["product_id"],
              "star_rating": x["star_rating"]
              })
```

**KeyError: in user code:**

```
       KeyError: 'customer_id'
```

The code that is in the tutorial works fine but does not work when I try to do it. I have been googling and could not find an answer.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks from now for your time.

Comment: It seems that is caused by how you are accessing the `data` In the tutorial that you follow does access the data in this way? I mean using:                                                      data = data.map(lambda x: {
               "customer_id": x["customer_id"],
               "product_id": x["product_id"],
              "star_rating": x["star_rating"]
              })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "data" key when accessing the dictionary.

This should fix it :

```
data = data.map(lambda x: {
        "customer_id": x["data"]["customer_id"],
        "product_id": x["data"]["product_id"],
        "star_rating": x["data"]["star_rating"]
       })
```